# Attempting to use a global array inside of a JS file shared between 2 HTML files and failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have one HTML page which consists of a bunch of form elements for the user to fill out. I push all the selections that the user makes into one global variable, `allTheData[]` inside my only Javascript file.

Then I have a 2nd HTML page which loads in after a user clicks a button. This HTML page is supposed to take some of the data inside the allTheData array and display it. I am calling the function to display allTheData by using:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('Two') > -1) {
        carousel();
    }
}

function carousel() {
    console.log("oh");
    alert(allTheData.toString());
}
```

However, I am finding that nothing gets displayed in my 2nd HTML page and the allTheData array appears to be empty despite it getting it filled out previously in the 1st HTML page. I am pretty confident that I am correctly pushing data into the allTheData array because when I use alert(allTheData.toString()) while i'm still inside my 1st HTML page, all the data gets displayed.

I think there's something happening during my transition from the 1st to 2nd HTML page that causes the allTheData array to empty or something but I am not sure what it is. Please help a newbie out!

Comment: You're calling `window.location.href.indexOf('Two')`, which is **`case sensitive`**. Are you sure that **`Two`** is actually part of the second page's URL?

Comment: Yep! I believe it works because "oh" gets logged into the console when the 2nd page loads in.

Comment: So, where is the second page getting that data from?

Comment: @yezzz the second page is connected to the single Javascript file so from the allTheData array there? at least that's what i was hoping for :(.

Comment: In a browser, the global scope is the `window` object.  If you replace the window, you replace the global scope.

Comment: @bob Nope... a page loads javascript code or a js file, then the browser executes it. When you load a new page (in the traditional way) all code and variables is gone, so you have to store it somewhere before switching the page. Eg. with cookies or webstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web Storage**: This sounds like a job for the `window.sessionStorage` object, which along with its cousin `window.localStorage` allows data-as-strings to be saved in the users browser for use across pages on the same domain.

However, keep in mind that they are both Cookie-like features and therefore their effectiveness depends on the user's Cookie preference for each domain.

A simple condition will determine if the web storage option is available, like so...

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {
   // continue with app ...
} else {
   // inform user about web storage
   // and ask them to accept Cookies
   // before reloading the page (or whatever)
}
```

Saving to and retrieving from web storage requires conversion to-and-from `String` data types,  usually via JSON methods like so...

```
// save to...
var array = ['item0', 'item1', 2, 3, 'IV'];
sessionStorage.myApp = JSON.stringify(array);

// retrieve from...
var array = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myApp);
```

There are more specific methods available than these.  Further details and compatibility tables etc in [Using the Web Storage API @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It's just what I needed.

Comment: @bobthebuilder4t5 No probs :)